# Command to display on which application pool the specific website is running

Tags: iis

is there any command where we can get to know about a particular website (IIS server) on which application pool is it running .

For Example :
if I wanted to know about what app pool does the "defaultwebsite" is running which command helps me to get the desired result .

please help me on this.

Regards,
Vikas Chandra.C

Answer (score 0):

You could run the powershell cmd-let`Get-WebApplication -Site "Default Web Site"`, assuming that it is IIS 7.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790554.aspx

IIS 7 powershell commands
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx

Comment: I  have tried the Cmd-let get-webapplication -site "Default Web Site", but it gave me an error

Comment: Then i need more information. What operation system are you running? What version of IIS and powershell are you running?

Comment: Did you load the IIS powershell module before usibg th command? Could you copy the error to this question?

Comment: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard ,IIS 7.5 ,power shell Version : 2.0

Comment: Get-WebConfiguration : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WebApplication -Site "Default Web Site"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WebConfiguration], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.GetConfigu
   rationCommand

Comment: Could be a problem wiht 64/32 bit modules. Could you try running both the `x86 version` and the `standard` powershell `as administrator`. Start by running the cmd `Import-Module WebAdministration` and then test by using the `Get-Command Get-Web*`. Please post the results in your question.

Comment: PS C:\> Get-Command Get-WebApplication -site "Default Web Site"

CommandType     Name                                                Definition
-----------     ----                                                ----------
Cmdlet          Get-WebApplication                                  ...

Comment: Finally The above command worked for me only difference was instead of passing argument in double quotes we have to put in single quotes. for example Get-WebApplication -Site 'Default Web Site'